# Compare two dataframes in pandas

Tags: pandas, forecast

I am a beginner. I have two dataframes in pandas, I would like to identify what are the changes from the original to the new dataframe.

- Rows: products
- Columns: demand for future periods

dataframe differences could be: new rows, deleted rows, and changed demand.

Ideally I would make a heatmap (showing changes) ... but I'm stuck - unsure if I have to iterate over or not ...

A record in a dataframe is:

```
ProductId | demand_Month1 | demand_Month2 | demand_Month3 ... MonthX
```

This data is monthly updated. I would like to generate the following table

```
productID | old - new (demand) ... for each month.
```

Dataframes contain same months demand data.

Comment: please provide sample dfs - there are a ton of things that could be compared (size/dimension? datatype? data values? is null?)

Answer (score 0):

```
def dataframe_difference(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame, which=None):
    """Find rows which are different between two DataFrames."""
    comparison_df = df1.merge(
        df2,
        indicator=True,
        how='outer'
    )
    if which is None:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] != 'both']
    else:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == which]
    diff_df.to_csv('data/diff.csv')
    return diff_df
```

Look at this for a start